# How to debug 'Login failed for user' on an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Here's the error message that is stumping me:

[image]

My Web App seems to have the correct connection string.  This is exactly what Azure provides me when I click Show Connection String:

```
Server=tcp:myservertest.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseTest;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Here's the connection string that I put in the Visual Studio Publish Settings Default Connection setting:

```
Server=tcp:myservertest.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseTest;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*****;Password=***********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

[image]

I have confirmed the username and password are correct...I used the same ones to connect via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I tried setting up the Diagnostic settings as follows, but I'm not exactly sure where I can find the resulting logs.  I don't see them in Kudo services, but I believe they'd be accessed elsewhere.

Does anyone know where they're stored?

Also, what other ways could this *Login failed for user* error message be debugged?

[image]

Comment: Could you see `appsettings.json` inside `Kudu` and ensure that connection string is correct?

Comment: @Win Where in Kudu would that be found?  Justin in the general file explorer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error looks like you are able to connect to the server but the server rejects the login. Debugging in the server logs would help, so you are looking at the right place.

You can enable Azure SQL Database Auditing & Threat Detection. You can enable it on SQL Server instance level by opening your SQL Server resource and selecting Security / Auditing & Threat Detection. Select a storage account to store logs in Storage details (see picture below). For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing.
[image: Auditing & Threat Detection settings]

After enabling auditing try to login to your database. After that you can find the logs in the specified Azure Storage Account in blob container named **sqldbauditlogs**. The logs are in folder /servername/databasename/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit_NoRetention/yyyy-mm-dd/ in files with xel extension. You can download and open the .xel -file in SSMS (File / Open / File…). The xel file contains events and you can see login attempts there.

Event field **succeeded** tells if the login failed or not, and field **server_principal_name** contains the username in both cases.
From text in field **additional_information** you can find error_code (in the xml). Error code 40615 is blocked by firewall and code 18456 is wrong username or password. (error codes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages)

You can also find some information in the database system tables for analysing the connections, e.g. sys.event_log (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current).

More information on troubleshooting the Azure SQL Database connectivity can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues.

I hope this helps you forward with debugging the connection.

Comment: It showed me 18456...which led me to the Web App Application Settings...which had the incorrect password.  All the appsettings.*.json files had the correct ones, but apparently it uses only the setting that's within the Azure portal.  Not sure why that wasn't apparent to me earlier.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Good that you found the solution. This is what debugging is for... ;-) Unfortunately in Azure SQL Database debug settings are scattered in multiple places and finding and setting them up requires some experience. On the other hand there are many possibilities for debugging, auditing and monitoring the PaaS database.

Comment: I'm currently troubleshooting a login failed issue but there is no sign of it in the Audit  Log or even the extended events.

Comment: If the exact error was "Login failed for user...", it is from the server and should be found there if logging is configured correctly. Are you sure you are targeting correct server? Please check also Microsoft troubleshooting tool for connectivity issues at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database.

Answer (score 2):

You've verified that `Allow access to Azure services` is ON.  This is generally where we get tripped up.  If it was coming from an outside place, we'd want to check the IP list here.  Knowing that's not it, let's dig deeper.

You've gotten into the Kudu console to verify all the things.  From that console, install [`mssql-cli`](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli).  Run [`pip install mssql-cli`](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/installation/windows.md#windows-installation) from the Kudu console.  If that doesn't work, look for [direct urls](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/installation_guide.md#direct-downloads) curl or download to your PC and use the [Kudu Console](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/) to upload the file into your app service.

Once you have the mssql-cli installed, try connecting with the credentials you've set in place in `appSettings.json`.  (See https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/usage_guide.md#options for command line options.)  Most probably, it'll spit out a nice error message about why it can't connect, giving you more clues.

If mssql-cli connects successfully, there's something overriding your app's settings.  Did you set the connection string in the Azure Portal's App Settings tab?  Temporarily, you might alter your app to write portions of the connection string to an obscure page.  And as soon as you get the info, DELETE THE PAGE and then [change the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

Another thing to try: grab all the details from the exception -- including `Data` and recursively through inner exceptions.  It probably has a clue buried in there.  You can [remotely debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) the app on Azure.  Before you can debug, you'll need to ensure you've turned on remote debugging and selected the correct version of Visual Studio from the App Settings blade in your App Service.

Comment: I'm using an Azure Web App, which are sandboxed...so I can't install software in the Kudu console.  Still working on the remote debugging suggestion.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be attaching to the remote debugger.  Curious if it's because of the _error while starting application_.  I tried setting a break point in all methods in **startup.cs** and **program.cs**, but nothing ever gets hit.

Comment: One can only remote debug a Debug build.  Perhaps you chose Release from the Configuration drop-down when publishing to Azure?  Try re-publishing from Visual Studio, and intentionally choosing Debug.

Comment: If you can't install, you can copy the exe -- even if you put it in your app's bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

> *Continue from comment* - Where in Kudu would that be found? Justin in the general file explorer?

Go to `Debug console > CMD` - `site > wwwroot` - click `Edit icon`

[image]

Also ensure that `Allow access to Azure services` is `ON`.

[image]

Comment: I see my 4 appsettings files (appsettings.json, appsettings.production.json, appsettings.Staging.json, appsettings.Testjson).  They all seem to have the correct settings except for the .production one.  I'm not in the production environment yet.

Comment: Could you change the connection string in production and test it again just in case deployment accidentally alters to production environment?

Comment: I tried changing the Production file, but the same result exists.  "Login failed for user 'my_user_name'

Comment: It is strange. Could you ensure that `Allow access to Azure services` is `ON`?

Comment: Verified:  In the Database->Firewall Settings...it is set to ON.

Comment: I'm just curious. If you are willing to write few line of code, then read the connection string, and spit out to the UI, and see it is the same connection string you expected.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can write out to the UI when I'm getting _an error starting the application_. I can't even get the home page to come up (when running through Azure Web App & SQL Database...it loads if I use SQLite & Azure Web App).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to check the connection string on azure application in azure. Maybe the connection string is different from the one in your web.config
[image]