# Connect AWS QuickSight to an Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, azure

I'm trying to use AWS QuickSight to analyse some data that is being stored in SQL Server on an Azure SQL server.

According to QuickSight, it can connect to an SQL Server, but whenever I try to validate the connection, the process hangs for about a minute then comes back with 'Cannot open server "*.*.*.*" requested by the login. The login failed.'

I initially suspected that this was an issue with the firewall on the MS SQL server on Azure.  Accordingly,  [I looked up the IP regions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/regions.html)

The region I am using is US West (Oregon) (us-west-2), so I white-listed the IP range 54.70.204.128 to 54.70.204.159 - but I am still getting exactly the same 1 minute (or so) pause, before the error comes back in Quick Sight.

The exact error is:

> Your database generated a SQL exception. This can be caused by query timeouts, resource constraints, unexpected DDL alterations before or during a query, and other database errors. Check your database settings and your query, and try again.

If I click "Show Details" then I get a further message saying:

> Error details
>   region: us-west-2
>   timestamp:  XXX
>   requestId:  XXX
>   sourceErrorCode:40532
>   sourceErrorMessage: Cannot open server "*.*.*.*" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:*
>   sourceErrorState:   S0001
>   sourceException:    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
>   sourceType: SQLSERVER

Obviously some of the above has been redacted.

I cannot believe that QuickSight cannot connect to an Azure MS SQL database, so I'm wondering if anyone else had had this problem, and what their solution was?

Comment: "Login failed" usually means it actually managed to find and connect but your login is incorrect. Can you login using other methods with those credentials. It is _necessary_ in Azure SQL to specify a default database - make sure you do that

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermain - thanks for the comment.  The login details I am using are definitely correct (copied / pasted from a connection string) and I can confirm that connection string works in a variety of other methods.  Also, I am specifying a default database too, but thanks for pointing it out.  Have you managed to connect to an MS SQL Azure database from QuickSight by any chance?  At the moment I am starting to wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: No I've never used QuickSight. The sales blurb specifically mentions "AWS data sources including Amazon RDS" and "on-premises databases like SQL Server". I don't know if that's a specific exclusion of Azure SQL. The next thing to do is get more info on the login error from Azure SQL Logs using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539077/how-to-debug-login-failed-for-user-on-an-azure-sql-database it will tell you for example if it was wrong password, wrong login, no access to DB etc.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks @Nick.McDermaid.  I will investigate but for the time being I've spent so long trying to get QuickSight to speak to Azure MS SQL that I have had to give-up and revert to using Tableau, which was something I was trying to avoid.  If I return to this and get it working, I will post the solution here.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this document: [Relational Data Sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html)

You can use any of the following relational data stores as data sources for Amazon QuickSight:

- Amazon Athena
- Amazon Aurora
- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon Redshift Spectrum
- Amazon S3
- Amazon S3 Analytics
- Apache Spark 2.0 or later
- MariaDB 10.0 or later
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or later
- MySQL 5.1 or later
- PostgreSQL 9.3.1 or later
- Presto 0.167 or later
- Snowflake
- Teradata 14.0 or later

Note

You can access additional data sources not listed here by linking or importing them through supported data sources.

You can retrieve data from tables and materialized views in PostgreSQL instances, and from tables in all other database instances.

Amazon Redshift clusters, Amazon Athena databases, and Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) instances must be in AWS. Other database instances must be in one of the following environments to be accessible from Amazon QuickSight:

- Amazon EC2
- On your local network
- In a data center or some other internet-accessible environment

AWS QuickSight document doesn't say it support Azure SQL database, just said the supproted other database environments.

And others have asked this problems in AWS Discussion Forums, no one or AWS QuickSight official given the answer.

Reference: [Can Quicksight connect to Azure SQL Database?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=793708)

What we can guess that it doesn't support Azure SQL for now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does help, thanks.  Seems that it's not supported - at least, not in my experience and nobody on here has said that they've managed to get it working.

Comment: @ThomasOwen, yes, we can not find more about this. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). Or, please mark your's as the answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasOwen, Can you please accept it as answer? Or please mark yourself, .Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I myself had this issue and it seems many others did. However, as noted above, there is little to no documentation that provides the steps to connect Quicksight and Azure Sql Server.

The issues for myself were primarily in the details that I gave Quicksight. Most connections with Azure sql server database connect seamlessly with your basic information:

Server, Port, Database Name, Username, Password

However, AWS Quicksight was trying to connect to my Azure Sql server with JDBC authentification.

JDBC Authentification requires your Username input to be = "username"@"servername"

Example of Correct Connection:

Server: "servername".database.windows.net
Port: 1433
Database Name: "databasename"
Username: "username"@"servername"
Password: "password"

Lastly, I turned off the SSL checkbox. It did not work with SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

According to any Googling I have done, and the responses posted here, it appears that while there is no specific statement from AWS or Azure saying the two cannot be connected, equally there is no response to say that they can.  Interestingly, nobody has responded to say that they have already got it working.  My feeling at the moment is that it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

While Azure SQL is not explicitly listed as one of the [QuickSight data sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html), you can still use it as a data source. TLS/SSL is also supported now and I have tested it personally.

You just need to make sure to use the "username"@"servername" format for the Username, as mentioned by [Scotty Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612495/1453190).