# Azure SQL is not letting me create a SQL User

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

I have a Database server created in Azure [not a managed instance] and a Server Admin user was created, many SQL users were added and they were able to login without any issues. Now all of a sudden, SQL users  I newly create can't login. It's giving Login failed message with **Error# 18456**

Here are the SQL commands I am using to create the user [after logging in as Server Admin]:

1. CREATE LOGIN reportslogin WITH password='' - this in "master" database
2. CREATE USER reportsuser from LOGIN reportslogin - this is in MyDatabase
3. ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER reportsuser - this again is in MyDatabase

Now I disconnect the server and when I try reconnecting to the server using the reportsuser, I get this:

[image: Login Failed with Error 18456]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check, if user exist after you ran create User SQL? and check Server authentication?

Comment: Yes, I can see the user exists once I create the user.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539077/how-to-debug-login-failed-for-user-on-an-azure-sql-database

Comment: @Binoy you can not login you the database with the username. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error is caused by you database login name.

You should using the Login `reportslogin` to login the database, not the username `reportsuser` !

We must using the login name to access the Azure SQL database, not the username.

A login is a simple credential for accessing SQL Server. For example,

SQL Login is for Authentication and SQL Server User is for Authorization. Authentication can decide if we have permissions to access the server or not and Authorization decides what are different operations we can do in a database. Login are created at the SQL Server instance level and User is created at SQL Server database level.

Please reference:

1. [Login and SQL User](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/16/sql-server-difference-between-login-and-user-sql-in-sixty-seconds-070/)
2. [Difference between a User and a Login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server)

**Suggestions:**

1. create the login and user with the same name:

   `USE master
   CREATE LOGIN reportslogin  WITH password='Xunmi110'`

   `USE user_database
   CREATE USER reportsuser  FOR LOGIN  reportslogin
   ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER reportsuser`
2. One login for one user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leon.. It was my mistake that I tried to use Username to get in. Good catch... Thanks again...