# Error:Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory while connecting Azure SQL DB through Jmeter JDBC Configuration

Tags: azure, authentication, jmeter, multi-factor-authentication

Getting Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open server "xyz.co" requested by the login.  The login failed. ClientConnectionId:xxxxxx00-0xxx-xxx3-xxxx-0xxxxxxxxxx0)

When I am trying to configure and connect to Azure MS SQL DB to Jmeter JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter perspective you can only increase logging level for the JDBC driver, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml file* (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" level="debug" />
```

More information:

- [Tracing driver operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/tracing-driver-operation?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

In general the error means that your username is not known to the MSSQL server, you can try passing it as:

```
user@example.com@xyz.co
```

If this doesn't help I cannot add anything more than is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631093/2897748)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, but this did not help. as the login authentication was Active Azure Directory- Universal with MFA so it did not allow connecting through Jmeter installed on the local. Now using SQL authentication to connect.